# Analytic operator semigroup bounds

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Suppose that $A: D(A) \subset X \to X $ with $X$ Banach is the infinitesimal generator of an analytic semigroup. Then how do you show that

$$|(-A)^{\gamma}A^k e^{At}|_{L(X)}\leq M t^{-k-\gamma}$$
for every $t \geq 0$, for $\gamma \in (0,1), K=0,1$ ?

This could be found in [Da Prato - stochastic differential equations in infinite dimensions - p 131]

Anyway shouldn't the estimate hold for every $t \leq T$ with $T$ fixed?

Comment: I didn't try it out, but this can probably be proven using holomorphic functional calculus for generators of analytic semigroups. But probably there's also a more elementary approach.

Comment: but for T fixed or for every $t >0$?

Comment: If $A$ is a negative self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, then there is a constant $M>0$ such that this holds for all $t\geq 0$. Usually, the case of generators of analytic semigroups is similar, but of course this is no proof.

Comment: ok many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the proof of Theorem 6.13, Chapter 2 in Pazy's book:

> A. Pazy, Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations (Berlin: Springer)​, 1983.

Take $\alpha=\gamma+k$.